# Selenium - NoSuchElementException

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Here is my HTML code,

```html
    <div class="input-group-btn search-panel dropdown open">
    <input type="search" id="footerSearch" class="form-control search-input search-filter-component" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
    <span class="input-group-btn gosearch-btn">
            <button class="btn  search-filter-component" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
```

I am getting below error, Exception in thread "**main**"

```java
    org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:
    Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//span[@class='input-group-btn gosearch-btn']}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:368)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:473)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:361)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:360)
        at PncSite.EnterSite.main(EnterSite.java:35)
```

Thanks for your update. I tried with your xpath, but it's not working. It's displaying the same error.

Here is the HTML code and screenshot.

```html
    <div id="cssearch_nav" class="input-group searchfilter-group">
        <div class="input-group-btn search-panel dropdown">
            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle search-filter-component" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span id="search_concept">Customer</span>
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <a data-autocomplete="false" class="search-filter active-filter" id="customerNameFilter">Customer</a>
                </li>
    
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() 
                {
                    var eleId = 'customerNameFilter';
                    var searchTmpId = '504417871974215089';
                    var screenUrl = '/wbs/template/customer.jsp';
                    var searchField = 'customer.company_name_uc';
                    var parInputGroup= $("#"+eleId).parents("div.input-group:first");
                    
                    if(parInputGroup!=undefined &&parInputGroup.length>0)
                    {
                        var parId = $(parInputGroup).attr("id");
                        window[parId].addSearchFilter(eleId,searchField,searchTmpId,screenUrl);
                    }
                });
                </script>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <a data-autocomplete="false" class="search-filter" id="customerFilter">Customer No.</a>
                </li>
                
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() 
                {
                    var eleId = 'customerFilter';
                    var searchTmpId = '504417871974215089';
                    var screenUrl = '/wbs/template/customer.jsp';
                    var searchField = 'customer.entity_no';
                    var parInputGroup= $("#"+eleId).parents("div.input-group:first");
                    
                    if(parInputGroup!=undefined &&parInputGroup.length>0)
                    {
                        var parId = $(parInputGroup).attr("id");
                        window[parId].addSearchFilter(eleId,searchField,searchTmpId,screenUrl);
                    }
                });
                </script>
                <!--   FR Search -->
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <a data-autocomplete="false" class="search-filter" id="finreqFilter">Request No.</a>
                </li>
                
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() 
                {
                    var eleId = 'finreqFilter';
                    var searchTmpId = '2993108337328648426';
                    var screenUrl = '/wbs/template/finance_request.jsp';
                    var searchField = 'finance_request.entity_no';
                    var parInputGroup= $("#"+eleId).parents("div.input-group:first");
                    
                    if(parInputGroup!=undefined &&parInputGroup.length>0)
                    {
                        var parId = $(parInputGroup).attr("id");
                        window[parId].addSearchFilter(eleId,searchField,searchTmpId,screenUrl);
                    }
                });
                </script>
                <li class="dropdown-menu-item">
                    <a data-autocomplete="false" class="search-filter" id="trxFilter">Transaction No.</a>
                </li>
                
                <script>
                $(document).ready(function() 
                {
                    var eleId = 'trxFilter';
                    var searchTmpId = '7785538818744716350';
                    var screenUrl = '/wbs/template/financial_trx_details.jsp';
                    var searchField = 'financial_trx.entity_no';
                    var parInputGroup= $("#"+eleId).parents("div.input-group:first");
                    
                    if(parInputGroup!=undefined &&parInputGroup.length>0)
                    {
                        var parId = $(parInputGroup).attr("id");
                        window[parId].addSearchFilter(eleId,searchField,searchTmpId,screenUrl);
                    }
                });
                </script>
                <!--   Quote Search -->
                        
            </ul>
        </div>
        <input type="search" id="footerSearch" class="form-control search-input search-filter-component" name="x" placeholder="Search term...">
        <span class="input-group-btn gosearch-btn">
            <button class="btn  search-filter-component" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
        </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you please share your HTML code or screenshots .

Comment: Share your code that you have tried

Comment: Here is the code that I used,driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='input-group-btn search-panel dropdown open']"));
Thread.sleep(6000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='search_concept']"));
Thread.sleep(5000);
System.out.println("Performing Footer Search");
System.out.println("For Entering Text");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='footerSearch']")).sendKeys("Lex G");
  System.out.println("Clicking Search Icon");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='footerSearch']/following-sibling::span[@class='input-group-btn gosearch-btn']")).click();

Comment: Please correct it,if there is any errors

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to analyse 'Element not Found' exceptions when working with Selenium](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/41860/how-to-analyse-element-not-found-exceptions-when-working-with-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML code provided above, it seems like search textbox is inside the expanded drop-down. So we have to make sure drop-down remains opened while locating the 'Search' element.

You can use below-mentioned locators that we usually use in automation testing.
As per our understanding from HTML code, you can use below locators:

**For entering Text:**

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='footerSearch']").sendKeys("searchText");
```

**Click Search icon:**

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='footerSearch']/following-sibling::span[@class='input-group-btn gosearch-btn']").click();
```

Hope your issue will be resolved.
Further, if you still face any issue please provide screenshots of UI with HTML code of drop-down, so that we can provide more inputs.

Comment: Hi Kannathasan,Thanks for your update.I tired with your xpath,but its not working.Its again displays same error.Here is the

Answer (score 0):

- Please make sure that the drop-down menu is opened while you try to enter the Search Text
- Try to add the Thread.sleep() after the pressing the drop-down menu, sometimes the menu can be opened with the delay, so a driver can't find an element
- Did the driver enter the search text in the search field?